# Trying to implement "Like" functionality and "Wishlist" functionality. 1 intermediate table for both?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

Considering:

- A user can like many places, and a place can be liked by many users
- A user can add many places to his wishlist, and a place can be in the
  wishlist of many users

Both the "Like" and "Wishlist" functionality will be using many-to-many relationships. For both of these functionalities, I definitely need to link the Users table and the Places table since the users will like/wishlist certain places

Laravel's naming convention for pivot tables is singularized table names in alphabetical order separated by an underscore. So let's give an example with the first example:

My first intermediate table which will be used for storing the likes will be called Place_User. It's all fine and dandy so far.

HOWEVER, my second intermediate table also connects the Users and Places tables, it just doesn't store the liked places but the wishlisted places so that means the second table should also be called Place_User. This will obviously lead to some problems.

I have already finished the like functionality and as soon as I started the wishlist functionality, I realized I already have all the tables I needed beside the intermediate table, however, as I explained by convention, the intermediate table for the wishlists should be called the same as the intermediate table for likes.

What am I meant to do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just name your pivot tables in a different way, like `place_user_like` and `place_user_wishlist`.

Then in your User model you can write this

```
public function likedPlaces() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Place', 'place_user_like');
}

public function wishlistedPlaces() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Place', 'place_user_wishlist');
}
```

Comment: May I ask 2 questions about this? First of all, if I'm not following the naming convention to begin with, can I just name the tables Likes and Wishlists instead of place_user_like and place_user_wishlist? Also do I have to change their names because I have not thought my database through or is it necessary for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: You can name your tables as you wish, but I suggest you to keep a lowercase/underscored pattern to be more consistent. But once you tell laravel which table to look for, everything works.